# Adapt Div area to Background img size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I haven't found any solution for this problem but I'm sure that one exists.

I have 4 `div`s with background images, together comprising a graphical option wheel.

The problem is that each `div`'s background image is triangular, but the area that is occupied by the `div` is bigger and is a square.  When I pass the cursor over each `div`, it is not working well, because the first `div` overlaps on top of the second, the second over the third, etc.

I thought about using `z-index` but that won't work because the first and the second div overlap one another, and so do the third and fourth.

I'm not sure if I've explained my problem very well. If you don't understand something, please let me know.

Here is an image to help you understand what I mean.

[image]

Thanks!!

**UPDATE WITH CODE**

Here is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/ialex90/x7mx1zqu/

Comment: Please add working bits of code to help us reproduce and debug your problem.

Comment: This can only be solved using SVG.

Comment: @klaar I just uploaded with the code

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Could you give me more information about what I have to use to implement SVG with that problem? becuase I never used it, thanks!

Comment: @Pete I thought in image map but because once i used it but it was a only image, in this case, are 4 diferent, is that possible?

Comment: @Pete I hid the rest of the code, but I have to use 4 images because when the cursor is on one of them, change the image (hover) that's the reason

Comment: @Pete while a fine approach you can see the mouse movements are off in your example, especially near the center of the wheel. In my example you can see the hover behaviour perfectly follows even the arcs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only achieve this effect with SVG. See the following base implementation that illustrates how you can both apply CSS and JS to irregular shapes using SVG:

```js
$('path').click(function(e) {
  alert(e.target.id);
});
```

```css
path {
  stroke:red;
  stroke-width:1;
  fill:rgba(255,0,0,0.15);
  transition:fill 0.5s;
}
path:hover {
  fill:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 250" width="500" height="250">
  <g>
    <path id="quadrant1" d="M0,250 A250,250 0 0,1 73,73 L161,161 A125,125 0 0,0 125,250 z" />
    <path id="quadrant2" d="M73,73 A250,250 0 0,1 250,0 L250,125 A125,125 0 0,0 161,161 z" />
  </g>  
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, I thinik that's all that i need!